# what does this sentence mean? can you break it into several simple sentences

Tags: sentence-structure

***Though, I do believe that there will be some who also have a better handle on what NOT to do as a mentor, having suffered themselves.***

what does the upper sentence mean? can you break it into several simple sentences. here are the full context:

I think this problem won't go away even if the older generation moves on (ie dies). Academic science is self-selecting those who buy into this system, as anyone else with the sense to avoid this environment will choose to leave. These are the next generation of PIs--selected to be super cutthroat. Though, I do believe that there will be some who also have a better handle on what NOT to do as a mentor, having suffered themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've upvoted @insanity's answer, but I'd like to provide an alternative as well:

- Because this next generation of PIs has suffered at the hands of their current mentors, some of these next-generation PIs will understand better what NOT to do as a mentor, I believe.

> This next generation of PIs has suffered.
>
> This next generation of PIs has suffered at the hands of their mentors.
>
> Because this next generation of PIs has suffered at the hands of their current mentors, some of the PIs from this next generation should understand what to do as a mentor...
>
> ...and what not to do.
>
> I, as the writer, believe all of the above to be true.

As @insanity has mentioned, "having a handle" on something means [to understand something well](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/have-get-a-handle-on-something) (Macmillan Dictionary).

Meanwhile, this "next generation" of PIs have "suffered" at the hands of their mentors.

Thus, because of their own suffering, they will understand better how to keep the people they mentor in the future from "suffering."

I put "suffering" in quotes because we are not sure exactly what sort of "suffering" the PIs have undergone without further context.

Comment: Your answer is much more detailed than mine. +1

Comment: @insanity, heh, thanks. Inspiration had struck was all :D. And couldn't have done it without you :).

Answer (score 1):

"I believe that there will be some people of the next generation, who have a better handle on what they should NOT do as a mentor. They would know, having suffered themselves. (at the hands of less than ideal mentoring)"

Here, having a handle on something means to understand something well. Since they've been at the receiving end of some mentoring mistakes, they understand well that they ought not to repeat them when they'll be mentoring someone themselves.

Answer (score 0):

> Though, I do believe that there will be some who also have a better
>   handle on what NOT to do as a mentor, having suffered themselves.

```
Though, I do believe
there will be some
    who also have a better handle 
             on what NOT to do
                 as a mentor    
having suffered themselves
```

However, I do believe

(that) there will be some [people]

who also have a better grasp on [better understanding of]

the things which should not be done

by a person who is a mentor

because they have had their own bad experiences [as a protégé].